Regarding the monotone class lemma; Folland's real analysis text
Consider the monotone class lemma in Folland's real analysis text below. A monotone class is a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ which is closed under countable increasing unions and countable decreasing intersections. An algebra is also a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ which is closed under complements and finite intersections and unions. I assume you know what a $\sigma$-algebra is.
I understand everything in this proof except the reason why the author states that $\varnothing$ and $E$ are in $\mathcal C(E)$ in the 3rd sentence. I see how this is true for $\varnothing$ and $E$; it follows from the fact that he states that $E\in\mathcal C$ in the beginning of the 2nd sentence and that $\varnothing\in\mathcal A\subset\mathcal C$. But where in the proof is this required/used?

$\textbf{2.35 The Monotone Class Lemma} \,\,$ If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $X$, then the monotone class $\mathcal{C}$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$ coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Proof. Since $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class, we have $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{M}$; and if we can show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we will have $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C}$. To this end, for $E \in \mathcal{C}$ let us define
$$
\mathcal{C}(E) = \{ F \in \mathcal{C} : E \setminus F, F \setminus E, \text{ and } E \cap F \text{ are in } \mathcal{C} \}.
$$
Clearly $\varnothing$ and $E$ are in $\mathcal{C}(E)$, and $E \in \mathcal{C}(F)$ iff $F \in \mathcal{C}(E)$. Also, it is easy to check that $\mathcal{C}(E)$ is a monotone class. If $E \in \mathcal{A}$, then $F \in \mathcal{C}(E)$ for all $F \in \mathcal{A}$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra; that is, $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}(E)$, and hence $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{C}(E)$. Therefore, if $F \in \mathcal{C}$, then $F \in \mathcal{C}(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{A}$. But this means that $E \in \mathcal{C}(F)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{A}$, so that $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}(F)$ and hence $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}(F)$. Conclusion: If $E, F \in \mathcal{C}$, then $E \setminus F$ and $E \cap F$ are in $\mathcal{C}$. Since $X \in \mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}$ is therefore an algebra. But then if $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{C}$, we have $\bigcup_{1}^{n} E_j \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $n$, and since $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under countable increasing unions it follows that $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty} E_j \in \mathcal{C}$. In short, $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and we are done. $\qquad \blacksquare$

